# Python scipy.optimize.minimize returns the initial guess. Is my function the problem?

Tags: python, r, scipy-optimize, ensemble-learning, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm working with an ensemble of precipitation data and I want to post-process. One technique that I want to try is EMOS (Ensemble Model Output Statistics). There is an R package called [EnsembleMOS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ensembleMOS/ensembleMOS.pdf) that does the job. However, since most of my other scripts are Python, I want to translate the **ensembleMOScsg0** part of that package to Python.

The problem that I'm facing is that scipy.optimize.minimize is returning the initial guess. I've found many different questions with a similar issue, and the answers were almost always related to some kind of problem on the function that is minimized.

My function:

```
def crps(train,obs,pars):
  a = pars[0]
  c = pars[1]
  d = pars[2]
  shift = pars[3]

  # print(a,c,d,pars[6])

  media = a
  crps = 0
  for i in range(len(train)):
    var = np.var(train.iloc[i])
    for j in range(len(train.columns)-1):
      media += pars[j + 4]*train.iloc[i,j]

    dp = c + d*var

    shape = (media**2)/(dp)
    scale = dp/media

    gamma = ss.gamma.cdf
    beta = ss.beta.rvs

    x = obs.iloc[i]

    z = (x + shift**2)/scale
    cc = (shift**2)/scale

    crps += scale*z*(2*gamma(z,a=shape)-1) \
      - scale*cc*(gamma(cc,a=shape))**2 \
      + media*(1+2*gamma(cc,a=shape)*gamma(cc,a=shape+1)-gamma(cc,a=shape))**2 \
      - 2*gamma(z,a=shape+1) \
      - media*(1-gamma(2*cc,a=shape)) \
      * beta(0.5,shape) \
      /np.pi

  return crps
```

The objective of the minimization is to find the parameters of a linear regression equation and its variance, that's why I separated the first 4 pars (**a** the intercept, **c** and **d** from the variance and the **shift** part of the gamma distribution) from the other 12 (the **b**'s, since I have 12 ensemble members, I need 12 b's).

The minimization part is:

```
pars = [0.0001,0.0001,0.0001,0.0001] + [0.0001]*12
bnds = ((.0001,20),) * 4
bnds = bnds + ((.0001,20),) * 12
result = minimize(partial(crps,train,obs),pars,method='L-BFGS-B',bounds=bnds)
```

The process ends with a success flag, but it always converges to the initial values.
Now I'm thinking about using **rpy2** and running this package directly with Python.

More information about this procedure can be found on [Baran and Nemoda (2016)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/env.2391).